# rpn calculator how to handle e?

Tags: c++, rpn

I really dont know how to handle with e. The calculator works for:

> 3e-3
>   3e3

Even when I write:

> -e or -e-

the calculator knows that this is an invalid input.

But when I write:

> 3-e-3 or 3-e3

the calculator doesn't recognize that this is an invalid input.

Can someone help me please?

I'm thinking of writing a function with `isdigit` to check if the input string is a digit or not. But does `isdigit` know pre-signs like `+` or `-`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
bool isOperator(const string& input);
void performOp(const string& input, stack<double>& RechnerStack);

// Main
int main()
{
    cout << "Der UPN Taschenrechner" << endl;

    stack<double> RechnerStack;
    string input;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << ">>";
        cin >> input;
        double Zahl;
        if (istringstream(input) >> Zahl)
        {
            RechnerStack.push(Zahl);
        }

        else if (isOperator(input))
        {
            performOp(input, RechnerStack);
        }

        // check for quit
        else if (input == "q")
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // invalid output
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool isOperator(const string& input)
{
    string ops[] = { "-", "+", "*", "/" }; // string array mit verfügbaren Operatoren

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (input == ops[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void performOp(const string& input, stack<double>& RechnerStack)
{
    double zahl1, zahl2, ergebnis;

    zahl2 = RechnerStack.top();
    RechnerStack.pop();

    zahl1 = RechnerStack.top();
    RechnerStack.pop();

    if (input == "-")
    {
        ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
    }
    else if (input == "+")
    {
        ergebnis = zahl1 + zahl2;
    }
    else if (input == "*")
    {
        ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
    }
    else
    {
        ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;
    }

    cout << ergebnis << endl;
    RechnerStack.push(ergebnis);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare (number-e) is a wrong input ?

Comment: Does e denote the euler-constant (2.71) ? For me it is surprising to see that istringstream("e")>>Zahl works.

Comment: e stands for *10^ (example: 5e-3 == 5*10^-3)

Comment: In order to validate input I suggest using a regular expression (regex). The include is <regex>.  To find the appropriate regex you can use https://regex101.com.